# jQuery - Enlarge Tab

Tags: jquery

I hava a website with a navigation bar which consists of several tabs. Now I would like to enlarge a tab as soon as a user moves the mouse over it. To make this more clear, here are two pics that should illustrate what I mean.
This pic shows the navigationbar in standard mode:[image]

And now as soon as a mouseover happens, the tab should look like this:
[image]

I know that this can be done with jQuery. Unfortunately though, I couldn't find an appropriate solution or plug-in.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

enne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something?
http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/fisheye-javascript-menu
or 
http://www.tympanus.net/Tutorials/FreshBottomSlideOutMenu/
or

Comment: Well, not bad, but the thing is that the navigationbar is a picture and on http://www.tympanus.net/Tutorials/FreshBottomSlideOutMenu/  it is completely made with css, so I have no idea how to use this in my case.

Comment: This is pretty simple taks. Just view its source and you will have an idea if you have lil bit knowledge of HTML and jquery.